# Extending the available space in a mirrored ZFS pool with zpool add?

Tags: zfs

I have a **mirror pool with two devices** (`sda, sdb`) on my **Debian**.

And now I inserted **two additional devices** (`sdc, sdd`), so I could **double the available space** in the `/mnt/data/` directory.

Is it done by just `sudo zpool add backup-pool mirror sdc sdd`?

I'm a bit scared so I want to make sure. Sorry for the rookie question.

Here are the details of my pool:

sudo zfs list

```
NAME               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
backup-pool       1.47T  1.17T       96K  /backup-pool
backup-pool/data  1.47T  1.17T     1.47T  /mnt/data
```

sudo zpool list

```
NAME          SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
backup-pool  2.72T  1.47T  1.25T        -         -    11%    53%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ABB57994-974B-734A-A2A9-2BA616368A52

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EFAX-68J
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DCDDA5ED-CB54-C042-9AF6-076F07F44E96

Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 5860515839 5860513792  2.7T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  5860515840 5860532223      16384    8M Solaris reserved 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer:

> Is it done by just `sudo zpool add backup-pool mirror sdc sdd`?

Yes.

### Long answer:

> I'm a bit scared so I want to make sure.

It's often simpler than one might think to test using non-critical devices, such as small virtual memory disks or in this case, file-backed virtual disks.

This is on FreeBSD, but Linux has tools to do the same thing.

I'll create four files of 1G each and use each file as a file-backed virtual disk:

```
# for i in $(jot 4 0)
> do
>         truncate -s1G md$i
>         mdconfig -f md$i
> done
```

I now have drives `/dev/md0` through `/dev/md3` to play with.  I'll create the original single-VDEV pool you have by mirroring `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md1`:

```
# zpool create tank mirror md0 md1
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md0     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

### The Wrong Way:

If you try to add the next disk `md2` to the pool, `zpool` warns that you're down-grading the redundancy of the pool:

```
# zpool add tank md2
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
mismatched replication level: pool uses mirror and new vdev is disk
```

And indeed if you do force this operation, and likewise force the addition of `md3` you get:

```
# zpool add -f tank md2
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md0     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0
          md2       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

# zpool add -f tank md3
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md0     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0
          md2       ONLINE       0     0     0
          md3       ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Notice that devices `md2` and `md3` have no redundancy.  Your pool is vulnerable to any of three failures: 1) if BOTH halves of the mirror fail; 2) if disk `md2` fails; or 3) if disk `md3` fails.  Any one of those three events will make your pool unusable.

## The Better Way:

My example above is simply to show what happens when you do it the wrong way.  The better method, indeed the one which I believe you are seeking, is to add the two new drives as a second mirror, concatenated with the first mirror.

For improved redundancy, tell `zpool` that you want to add a mirror to the existing pool:

```
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md0     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

# zpool add tank mirror md2 md3
# zpool status tank
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
config:

        NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank        ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md0     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md1     ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
            md2     ONLINE       0     0     0
            md3     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```